# Entity value is entire utterance if utterance doesn't exist as an exact training phrase

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have a custom `Entity` which is configured as allowing synonyms but without "fuzzy matching" and "allow auto expansion". This entity exists in an intent with a lot of training phrases.

For this problem, let's say I have an entity named `Fruit` with the values `apple` and `pear` as well as a training phrase that is "`I would like to buy a $fruit`".

If I invoke this intent with a phrase that exists as a training phrase I get my entity value resolved nicely.

But if I'd invoke the intent with an utterance, that includes an entity value, but doesn't exist as a training phrase the entity value is resolved to the entire utterance, which of course isn't what I want.

For instance if the user says "I think I would like an apple", the `parameters.fruit` value is "`I think I would like an apple`".

Now if a user would say this exact utterance once more a few seconds or minutes later, then the entity $fruit is resolved nicely to "`apple`" as a parameter to my intent (conv.parameters.fruit = "apple").

How do I configure my intent/entity to always resolve the entity value correctly? This is really frustrating since it's a simple, stupid entity (enum) I'm trying to use. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am unable to reproduce your issue, this would be a bug on the Dialogflow side.

Can you try again and confirm you are still receiving this issue?

Also ensure you only have `Define synonyms` enabled for your custom entities, and that the highlighted portions of all of your training phrases only includes the name of the entity value.

Regardless, I have filed a bug internally to further investigate this issue.

Best,